# How is `new (std::nothrow)` implemented?

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

I have a C++ program where the `new` operator is overloaded. The problem is that
if my allocation in the `new` operator fails, I'm still calling the constructor.
I know I can avoid this by throwing `std::bad_alloc`, but I don't want to do that.

How can I fail in my overloaded `new` operator and still not call my constructor?
Essentially I want to implement something like `new (std::nothrow)`.

Here's an example to illustrate what I mean. **Note that the system I'm testing
on has no memory protection. So accessing `NULL` doesn't do anything**

*Example 1 : Overloaded new operator*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory>

class Test {

public:

    Test(void) {
        printf("Test constructor\n");
    }

    void print(void) {
        printf("this: %p\n", this);
    }

    void* operator new(size_t size, unsigned int extra) {

        void* ptr = malloc(size + extra);
        ptr = NULL; // For testing purposes
        if (ptr == NULL) {
            // ?
        }
        return ptr;
    }
};

int main(void) {

    Test* t = new (1) Test;            
    t->print();
    printf("t: %p\n", t);

    return 0;
}
```

The ouput for this is:

```
$ ./a.out
Test constructor
this: 00000000
t: 00000000
```

Clearly the *constrcutor is getting called when the `new` failed*.

*Example 2 : Huge class declaration with new (std::nothrow)*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory>

class Test {

    int x0[0x0fffffff];
    int x1[0x0fffffff];
    int x2[0x0fffffff];
    int x3[0x0fffffff];
    int x4[0x0fffffff];
    int x5[0x0fffffff];
    int x6[0x0fffffff];
    int x7[0x0fffffff];
    int x8[0x0fffffff];
    int x9[0x0fffffff];
    int xa[0x0fffffff];
    int xb[0x0fffffff];
    int xc[0x0fffffff];
    int xd[0x0fffffff];
    int xe[0x0fffffff];
    int xf[0x0fffffff];

public:

    Test(void) {
        printf("Test constructor\n");
    }

    void print(void) {
        printf("this: %p\n", this);
    }
};

int main(void) {

    Test* t = new (std::nothrow) Test;    
    t->print();
    printf("t: %p\n", t);

    return 0;
}
```

The ouput for this is:

```
this: 00000000
t: 00000000
```

Clearly the *constrcutor is **not** getting called when the `new` failed*.

So how do I implement `new (std::nothrow)` kind of functionality in my
overloaded `new` operator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whether the compiler checks for a null pointer after calling
`operator new` or not, before calling the destructor, depends on
whether the allocator function has a non-throwing exception
specification or not.  If not, the compiler assumes that
`operator new` will throw if no memory is available.  Otherwise,
it assumes that `operator new` will return a null pointer.  In
your case, your `operator new` should be:

```
void* operator new( size_t size, unsigned int extra ) throw()
{
    //...
}
```

or if you can count on C++11 support:

```
void* operator new( size_t size, unsigned int extra) noexcept
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I would never have guessed the answer. Just a question, whatever you said, is it documented anywhere in the C++2003 standard?

Comment: §5.3.4/13: "If the allocation function returns null,
initialization shall not be done, the deallocation function
shall not be called, and the value of the new-expression shall be
null."

Comment: Actually, in both C++11 and C++03, the behaviour is specified in `[basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]/3`. For C++11, the wording is: "If an allocation function declared with a non-throwing exception-specification fails to allocate storage, it shall return a null pointer. Any other allocation function that fails to allocate storage shall indicate failure only by throwing an exception of a type that would match a handler of type std::bad_alloc." The C++03 wording is very similar.